# Jquery: get attribute value of an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an online quiz app. The quizes are divided in terms of chapters such that each chapter has its own quiz. Each chapter is attached to a menu and onclick on a menu, a chapter is loaded with some content and at the end there's a button to start a quiz.

As the user takes the quiz, there's a button to navigate to the next question. on finishing the last question, the score for the quiz will be displayed alongside a button to click to be navigated to the next chapter. all this is to be done dynamically. what i want is, on this button that will navigate to the next chapter, i pass the id of the next chapter in this button

This is the jquery bit that is handling the last part i've described above(the click event handles submission of a question):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#page-content-wrapper").on('click', '.questionform #submit', function(e)  
     {
          //more code before this
          var next_chapter = $("a[data-menu='" + next_menu +"']")[0];
          console.log(next_chapter);
     });
});
```

the variable `next_chapter` holds the entire html link for the next menu. i.e.

`console.log(next_chapter);`

returns:

`<a href="#signs-giving-orders" id="2" data-menu="2">Signs Giving Orders</a>`

now what i want is to capture the `id` and pass it the button value. i've tried getting the id using both the `.find` and `.attr` methods as such:

```
var next_chapter = $("a[data-menu='" + next_menu +"']")[0].attr('id');
var next_chapter = $("a[data-menu='" + next_menu +"']")[0].find('a').attr('id');
```

but both the above throw an error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].attr is not a function` and  `Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].find is not a function` respectively.

So in short, how do i retrieve the id of this dynamic result: `<a href="#signs-giving-orders" id="2" data-menu="2">Signs Giving Orders</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because `.attr()` method of jQuery element, not native one

So do this

```
var next_chapter = $("a[data-menu='" + next_menu +"']")[0].id;
```

One more option

```
var next_chapter = $("a[data-menu='" + next_menu +"']")[0].getAttribute('id');
```

Also you can check https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp

And
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `[0]`, it returns the reference to native DOM element thus you were getting the error.

As you want to get the attribute value, directly use `.attr()` on jQuery object

```
var next_chapter = $("a[data-menu='" + next_menu +"']").attr('id');
                                                      //Notice [0] is removed
```